# OS X 10.11.2 - Python - Import video module error

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I'm trying to run the opencv python example lk_track.py,

the problem is the module video is not being founded on my Python installation, I tried to install using

```
brew install python
```

Still not working, even trying to change the python version setting on my .bash_profile.

```
>>> import video
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named video
>>>
```

The others OpenCV examples on C++ is working fine, it is just those Python's samples which is giving troubles.

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: It was 2.7.11, but I solved it the problem already, it was a module missing on my own project, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It was just a missing file from the sample folder, now it is ok.